# how to login into container when using ctr

Tags: containerd, ctr

I am using this command to start the container:

```
root@k8sslave01:~# ctr run --net-host --rm docker.io/nicolaka/netshoot:latest netshoot-container
```

then using this command to login into the container terminal:

```
ctr task exec --exec-id=568810 netshoot-container /bin/bash
```

but the command is always hangup. did not login into container. Am I missing something? what should I do to login into container? This is the ctr version info:

```
root@k8sslave01:~# ctr version
Client:
  Version:  1.6.20~ds1
  Revision: 1.6.20~ds1-1+b1
  Go version: go1.19.8

Server:
  Version:  1.6.20~ds1
  Revision: 1.6.20~ds1-1+b1
  UUID: bc5f157e-b0d4-494d-8cdc-188b15e17709
```